# TidCustomTCPServer.Active := False, never returns

Tags: delphi, indy

I downloaded some interesting code from [Indy 10 TIdTCPServer](https://mikejustin.wordpress.com/2014/04/19/indy-10-tidtcpserver-server-side-message-push-example/) and compiled and ran it. It's a bit messy and it probably needs work but it's a good foundation for something interesting. At least I don't have to post all the code here. Anyway, I decided that the `ExampleServer` needs to be de-activated first, not just freed in `OnDestroy`. So I added:

```
procedure TServerPushExampleForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ExampleServer.Active := False; // bug here - never returns
end;
```

To try to debug this, I added **IdCustomTCPServer.pas** to the project and stepped into it.

An exception is raised in `TIdCustomTCPServer.StopListening;` at the line `LListener.WaitFor;` This exception is trapped in the exception handler in `TIdListenerThread.Run;` but the `E.message` isn't retrieved there, so I had to modify the code there to get the message:

*"Operation Aborted"*

I traced it further after that, but the code execution eventually comes back to the same exception handler.

Is this a bug or is it just better to never set the Active property to False? In my tests, if I close the app and let the RTL manage all the free'ing. The infinite loop doesn't occur (the app does actually close)

Comment: Is this just bad implementation of ideas, or is some deeper issue uncovered here? `LListener.WaitFor;` raises "operation aborted" exception?

Comment: This is not a site for *Hey Fred. Can you personally look into this for me* posts. If you have a specific question, then write the question addressed to anyone and everyone that chooses to read it. This is not a social networking site, chat room, or discussion forum. And FYI, you can't ping just anyone using the @; that only works when you're replying to someone in a comment or who has left a comment to your question or answer. If they have not participated in your post at all, the ping doesn't reach them.

Comment: Ok, so now that I have your attention, do you have any comments (or perhaps even an answer) to the question?

Comment: Yes, I have a comment. As I said previously, *If you have a specific question, then write the question addressed to anyone and everyone that reads it*, which means you need to edit it to be more clear and specific what you're asking.

Comment: @Ken White: Sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The exception is normal behavior.

Indy uses blocking sockets.

`TIdListenerThread` runs a loop waiting for clients to connect.  Each wait is a blocking operation.

When the server is being deactivated, it closes its listening socket(s), causing pending socket operations to abort, and then the listening thread(s) are terminated. The abort exception is handled internally.

The server's destructor also sets `Active=False`, so whether you deactivate explicitly or not, the server will be deactivated.

This, in if itself, is not causing your hang. Typically, the only way setting `Active=False` can ever hang is if a server event handler tries to sync with the main UI thread synchronously while the main thread is blocked waiting for the server to deactivate. Classic deadlock scenario.

That does not appear to be the case in the demo you linked to, though (the only sync being used is asynchronous instead). So, something else is likely going on that your debugging hasn't reveiled yet.  There should be no hang.

Comment: Thanks Remy. I decided to rewrite the example from scratch to perform the same function (asynchronous readln), but in an entirely different way (using Indy components and anonymous threads, and I didn't get the problem I reported here.

Comment: In the process of writing a new app and debugging that, I found the reason for the server not going inActive. If there is data sent by the client that hasn't been read by the server (or vice-versa), the the server won't shut down.

Comment: @nolaspeaker that is certainly a possibility (at least the reading part). If there is unread data in the `IOHandler.InputBuffer` then `IOHandler.Connected` will be true even if the socket is closed. A `TIdTCPServer` socket thread will loop as long as its associated `IOHandler` is "connected" and can satisfy read operations without going back to the socket for more data. But once it does, the socket closure performed by the `Active` setter will cause a read error, which will terminate the thread if you let it. The `Active` setter waits for all socket threads to terminate.

Comment: Thanks again Remy. Of course, now that I know this, I can write better code, code that always matches the writes and the reads to prevent this situation from occurring.